# Access /proc/<pid>/ns/pid -> inode number

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-namespaces

I am trying to get access to inode number of pid namespace which can be seen using `ls -Li /proc/<pid>/ns/mnt` or `/proc/<pid>/ns/pid`.

I am a newbie to kernel code, want to know in kernel, from `current` task structure how can I get this value? Some code would really help.

Answer (score 2):

The current task structure can be looked into for `pid_namespace` struct, which has the this field `proc_inum`:

`task_active_pid_ns(current)->proc_inum;`

EDIT: From kernel version 3.19 onwards, the `pid_namespace` struct has received an update that includes the addition of the `ns_common` struct that is defined in the header file: `/include/linux/ns_common.h`.

The `ns_common` struct is defined as follows:

```
struct ns_common {
    atomic_long_t stashed;
    const struct proc_ns_operations *ops;
    unsigned int inum;
};
```

The new `pid_namespace` struct is defined to include `ns_common` struct and does not contain the `proc_inum` integer. Instead, the inode number can be accessed using the `ns_common` struct.

So, the inode number can be obtained (from kernel v3.19 onwards) with the following line:
`task_active_pid_ns(current)->ns_common->inum`

Source: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19/source/include/linux/pid_namespace.h